# JavaScript framework which uses the {{item}} syntax?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

## Context

I saw this in a source code.

## Question

What is the JavaScript framework which uses this syntax?

## Code

```
<script id='menu-candidacies-template' type='text/html'>
{{#candidacy1}}
  {{#candidates}}
    <img src="{{photo.sizes.small.url}}" width="50px" height="50px" valign="middle" />
  {{/candidates}}
{{/candidacy1}}
vs
{{#candidacy2}}
  {{#candidates}}
    <img src="{{photo.sizes.small.url}}" width="50px" height="50px" valign="middle" />
  {{/candidates}}
{{/candidacy2}}
</script>
```

Comment: If you saw the source, couldn't you figure out the framework?

Comment: Are there no clues in the rest of the source, for example an include of the framework that parses this?

Comment: The JS code is in an external file and it is unreadable ([link](http://voxe.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/web-d80501c91317a4ec1ed444ec10e719e4.js)).

Comment: Can be made readable with something like http://jsbeautifier.org/. Still difficult to find what you don't know to look for though. It does include Mustache in it though, and utilizes Backbone too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) and [JQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) and [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) that use `{{` and `}}` but mustache.js accepts `#` for the tag's key.

After inspecting the JS in the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423400/javascript-framework-which-uses-the-item-syntax/9423437#comment11913371_9423400) I have determined that this is indeed mustache.js version 0.4.0-dev released September 2011

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to **[handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)**, but looks more like **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)**.